# How to call this method in lua?

Tags: arraylist, lua, lua-table

So I'm trying to create an arrayList in lua following this module

https://github.com/SnakeSVx/spacebuild/blob/master/lua/includes/modules/arraylist.lua#L26

So first I started with

```
l = ArrayList:Create()
```

now I tried to create the list itself

```
l.list = List:Create()
```

However that's not the right way to do it. The method goes like this

```
function list:Create( thetype, isfunc )
self:SetCheckType(thetype, isfunc)
self.table = {}
end
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: This [l.list = List:Create() ] doesn't work, How can I instantiate an arrayList following the above module ?

Comment: Try `l = ArrayList.Create()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an object with that module, use the function documented for creating objects:

```
local l = ArrayList.Create()
```

`Create` is a non-method function in the namespace created by the module ("ArrayList"). It's definition and documentation begin on line 364.

Most of the other functions in module are methods. So, you would pass an instance to them using Lua's method syntax (`instance:method(...)`)

```
l:Add(item, index)
```

Comment: Okay if I did l = ArrayList.Create(), how can i start adding data l.Add() or l.list.Add() ??

Comment: Look at the source code. Does the table returned by `ArrayList.Create` have a `list` attribute?

Comment: Edited answer to explain method calling.